# Building failed because of "Package x11 not found"

Tags: application-development, packaging, launchpad

I am trying to build an application I am making into launchpad for my PPA, and, while **it builds the DEB just fine locally**, it fails in launchpad.

The build log complains that `Project ERROR: Package x11 not found` while I totally build-depend on `libx11-dev`, and a package named `x11` does not exist!

Here's the PPA     : https://launchpad.net/~hakermania/+archive/macropolo/+packages

The buildlog (i386): https://launchpadlibrarian.net/115106043/buildlog_ubuntu-precise-i386.macropolo_0.3-0ubuntu1_FAILEDTOBUILD.txt.gz

Can you please solve this mystery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparantly your program uses `pkg-config` in order to find compiler flags for the X11 library. However, you do not have that package added to your build dependencies, resulting in:

```
sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
```

Solution: add `pkg-config` to your `Build-Depends`.

Comment: Thanks. I've built quite a lot of packages in launchpad and this is the 1st time that I need to include `pkg-config` into the `Build-Depends` field. Can you please explain why?

Comment: Developers can choose to use `pkg-config` to determine whether a package is available. An alternative is checking whether a package compiles (assuming standard header and library directories). Read more about pkg-config in its manual page.